# CSS Grid - can you constrain auto column?

Tags: css, grid

I have a design consisting of 4 columns using CSS Grid. The css definition is:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto 450px 450px auto;
```

The two 450px centre columns have divs with some feature text & a related image respectively for a landing page. And the `auto` columns simply fill out the width of the page.

However, in the design the last feature image overflows the second 450px column and flows to the edge of the page. I have tried to:

- col span the image over the second 450px column and the auto column but it squeezes the first auto column to a much smaller width.

Is there a way that I can col span into the right hand `auto` column but not have the column grow to encompass the entire image?

Answer (score 0):

The following works as it calculates what the width of the 4th column would be:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto 450px 450px calc((100vw - 900px)/2);
```

and on the last feature image spans 2 columns:

```
grid-column: span 2;
```